# Select Data SQL to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-2012

I tried bind the DataGridView from Table "NatureCharge"

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.DataSource = null;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from NatureCharge", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        DataGridViewNatureCharge.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I need to show Nom Famille not the Id, so what is the modification on select query??? 
**"select * from NatureCharge where Idfam =(select NomFam from Famille)"**
[image]

**Update**
the problem with NomFam created in another cell in DatagridView.
I need to add it in 3rd cell.
**select n.IdNat,n.NomNat,f.NomFam from NatureCharge n join Famille f on n.IdFam=f.IdFam**

[image]
The DataGridView

```
//Set Columns Count
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.ColumnCount = 3;

        //Hide the last blank line
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        //Add Columns
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[0].Name = "IdNat";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[0].HeaderText = "N° Nature de Charge";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "IdNat";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[0].Width = 100;

        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Nom de Nature de Charge";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[1].Name = "NomNat";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "NomNat";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[1].Width = 150;

        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[2].Name = "IdFam";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Nom de Famille";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "IdFam";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[2].Width = 100;

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "";
        checkBoxColumn.Width = 30;
        checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn";
        DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL joins for this.

```
SELECT A.NomFam, B.IdNat, B.NomNat FROM Famille A join NatureChange B on A.IdFam = B.IdFam
```

Comment: Change the select order in query

Comment: nothing happen, it is the same result, see the query after upadet, and I already initialie the datagridview in the formas with the name and  headertext

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking. But I guess this is the problem: DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "IdFam"; Change it to DataGridViewNatureCharge.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "NomFam".